# How can I retrieve data from a cell?

Tags: openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl and I want to retrieve data. The following line

```
 cell_name_Target = ws.cell(row = 0, column = ColT).value
```

gives me an error message:

> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

How can I get the data from specific row and column into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl uses 1-based indexing for rows and columns.

Comment: Charlie Clark, thanks for the info. So the row starts with 1, 2, 3 and so on instead of 0,1,2,3... Please clarify

Comment: Yes, that is what 1-based indexing means.

Comment: I tried to start from '1' but still then the error persists. Please advise